# spinner setOnItemSelectedListener does not working

Tags: android, android-studio

anybody can help! the spinner listener doesn't work by this fragment.
it's never called
I have tried to implement an AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
I try to implement the spinner in Fragment I don't know if that really matter
Java code
'''

```
Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, users);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: " + position);
//its never called

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

'''

Comment: You did select the item, right? This is one of those questions that you will realize was so silly to post on StackOverflow. Please look at other spinner code examples and compare your code. Thank You

Comment: hey dear, 
yes I have shown almost all the questions about the problem I faced 
unfortunately, no answer is working for me 
Notice I have another spinner in another fragment wich work and I have copied it but it is still not working